# get elements from BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need to get only `x` and `y` from this soup's return, how can I do that, I tried using `split()` and `del()` in the string but it didn't work. Here's my code:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

uri = 'https://www.comprasparaguai.com.br/notebook-apple-macbook-pro-2022-apple-m2-memoria-8gb-ssd-256gb-133_42393/'
page = urllib.request.urlopen(uri)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

historico = soup.find(class_='chart-container')
print(historico)
```

My return:

```
['<div class="chart-container">\n<canvas data-historico="[{\'y\': 1409.0', " 'x': '07/2022'}", " {'y': 1235.0", " 'x': '08/2022'}", " {'y': 1150.0", " 'x': '09/2022'}", " {'y': 1187.0", " 'x': '10/2022'}", " {'y': 1187.0", ' \'x\': \'10/2022\'}]" id="grafico-modelo"></canvas>\n</div>']
```

How can I get `x` and `y` so I can build a graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the data as pandas DataFrame you can do:

```py
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

data = literal_eval(historico.canvas["data-historico"])

# uncomment this to print all data
# print(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
        y        x
0  1409.0  07/2022
1  1235.0  08/2022
2  1150.0  09/2022
3  1187.0  10/2022
4  1187.0  10/2022
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the element using a CSS selector, get the `data-historico` attribute, then parse the list with `ast.literal_eval()`. Like this:

```
from ast import literal_eval
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

uri = 'https://www.comprasparaguai.com.br/notebook-apple-macbook-pro-2022-apple-m2-memoria-8gb-ssd-256gb-133_42393/'
page = urllib.request.urlopen(uri)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

historico = soup.select('.chart-container>canvas')
data = literal_eval(historico[0]['data-historico'])
print(data)
```

If you want to make a graph, then you'll probably need a DataFrame.  All you'd need to do in that case is use `pandas.DataFrame()`. For example:

```
import pandas

# ... same code as above ...

historico_df = pandas.DataFrame(data)
print(historico_df)
```